# How to align the legend with the chart element?

Tags: dc.js

Legends are placed on default at the "Top-Left" with an additional offset for XY. What I would like to do is place the Legend at the "Bottom-Middle" (preferably without tweaking the XY)

Tried (1) -> Puts the legend in the "Top-Left"

```
var chart = dc.pieChart("#Chart");
chart
.width(600)
.height(600)
.legend(dc.legend().horizontal(true))
```

Tried (2) -> Makes the legend invisible

```
var chart = dc.pieChart("#Chart");
chart
.width(600)
.height(600)
.legend(dc.legend().horizontal(true).x(130).y(630))
```

Tried (3) -> Puts the legend on top of the pie-chart

```
var chart = dc.pieChart("#Chart");
chart
.width(600)
.height(600)
.legend(dc.legend().horizontal(true).x(130).y(570))
```

Tried (4) -> Makes the legend visible, but moves the chart a little bit down

```
var chart = dc.pieChart("#Chart");
chart
.width(600)
.height(700)
.legend(dc.legend().horizontal(true).x(130).y(670))
```

Tried (5) -> Throws an error "align is not a function"

```
var chart = dc.pieChart("#Chart");
chart
.width(600)
.height(700)
.legend(dc.legend().horizontal(true).align("Bottom-Middle"))
```

Did somebody figure out a workaround for this (perhaps a function for calculating XY)?

Comment: There is no automatic way to do this. I think you just have to do the math.